# Drools Integrate with OSGI (IDempiere)

Tags: java, drools, business-rules, idempiere

Am using Idempiere application which is (OSGI+Jetty), trying to intergate with business rule engine Drools..
I have taken simple helloworld example in drools 7.3.0v

**Code :**

```
  KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
  KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieClasspathContainer(getClass().getClassLoader());
  KieBase kbase = kContainer.getKieBase("rules");
  KieSession kSession = kbase.newKieSession();
```

when am try to execute this getting null pointer exception in **kContainer.getKieBase("rules");** because it can't find/reach **kmodule.xml**

But i have added in META-INF/kmodule.xml and specified in **build.properties**

```
source.. = src/,\
       resources/
bin.includes = META-INF/kmodule.xml,\
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.